# How do I make X and Y to reach their destinations at the same time?

Tags: animation, math, game-physics, axis

I'm learning how to write code for video games; specifically, player movement via mouse click. The problem I'm having, is depending on the destination, X can reach it's destination before Y, and vice versa. How do I make X and Y to reach their destinations at the same time?

Comment: Please explain more and give an example

Comment: Forgot to add, it's a 2D enviroment.

Comment: Compute the distance each object needs to travel. Divide each by the time they need to spend travelling. The result is the target velocity required for them to get there at the same time. It  gets more complicated if you wish the objects to speed up at the beginning and slow down toward the end, but it's basically all math. You might try dusting off your physics textbook, you're going to need it.

Comment: use linear interpolation `(x,y) = (x0,y0)  +   t / ( (x1,y1) - (x0,y0) );  t=<0.0,1.0>` or any other degree ....

Answer (score 1):

Let you have starting point `(x0,y0)` and end point `(x1,y1)`.

So coordinate differences are `dx = x1 - x0, dy = y1 - y0` - components of direction vector.

Find distance `Len = Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)` - length of vector

Get normalized direction vector components `udx = dx / Len, udy = dy / Len`

Now at every step (at timer event etc) change position corresponding to this formula: `x = x0 + V * udx * t, y = y0 + V * udy * t`, where V is velocity, t is time. This law describes linear movement.

Often it is worth to calculate and use velocity vector components `vx = V * udx, vy = V * udy` - in this case you can easily make reflection from borders (for vertical border - just negate `vx`) and so on.

Note that if your screen coordinates are integer, you have to round values before output (don't use previous step integer values for new step)